# Data reorganization - SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot

I have a question for reorganizing the data in SQL in the manner indicated below.

I have a table with the given data structure.

| Username | Type | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test | 1 | Data1 |
| test | 1 | Data2 |
| test | 1 | Data3 |
| test | 2 | Data1 |
| test | 2 | Data2 |
| test | 2 | Data3 |

Using query how can i get the view as given below? How can I make more columns from the last column, for those rows where the data in the first and second columns are the same?

| Username | Type | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test | 1 | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |
| test | 2 | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |

Comment: Perhaps `PIVOT` something, depending on the dbms you're using. (I.e. add a tag for the dbms you're using.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know in advance you just need three  values for each of your output records, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function to provide a ranking for each of your fields, then you can use conditional aggregation, using `CASE` expressions, to set each of your Data information in the specific  field. Eventually aggregate per <Username, Type> partition.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT tab.*, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserName, Type ORDER BY Data) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT Username, Type,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Data END) AS Data1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Data END) AS Data2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Data END) AS Data3
FROM cte 
GROUP BY Username, Type
```

This is likely to work on all most common up-to-date DBMS'.